# Can I use OpenGL context in React Native for Windows?

Tags: c++, react-native, game-engine, react-native-windows

I wonder if I can write my own native module, render something with using OpenGL in C++ and finally display rendered picture on react native side ( by simply using component).

If so, can I use that to render an animation in for example 60fps?

My case is that I've got the custom, let's say, game renderer written in OpenGL, and I looking for some fancy solution to create an editor detached from engine code.

I've already analyzed some react-native video libraries and I've discovered that frames are injecting as the texture of components, but I'm not sure is it the best solution (I can't find any documentation of those low-level mechanisms in react native).

Any advice? Thanks in advance!